# htaccess regex for all except some filetypes

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to set a rule in a directory cgi, this works but I would like to avoid it for .cgi .php and .html filetypes

```
<Files *>
    SetHandler default-handler
</Files>
```

Can I add that exception in a regex way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use `FilesMatch` with negative lookahead regex:

```
<FilesMatch "^(?!.*\.(cgi|php|html)$).*$">
    SetHandler default-handler
</FilesMatch>
```