# How to allow 403 page while all other pages are forbidden?

Tags: .htaccess

I was wondering how I could allow one page which would be the 403 page while the other pages are forbidden. This is what I tried in my `.htaccess` file but it didn't work - it didn't display the 403 page that I'd set with the `ErrorDocument`.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php

Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 203.0.113.111
```

Comment: What version of Apache are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the file to be allowed using the `<Files>` directive (which is processed later). For example:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 203.0.113.111
<Files "403.php">
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

To specify both your error documents, you can use the `<FilesMatch>` directive with a regex instead:

```
<FilesMatch "^40[34]\.php$">
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a *negative lookahead* to apply your blocking directives only to none error documents. For example:

```
<FilesMatch "^(?!40[34]\.php$).*$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 203.0.113.111
</FilesMatch>
```

See also anubhava's answer to this question:
[htaccess regex for all except some filetypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099426/htaccess-regex-for-all-except-some-filetypes)

---

Another way is to use mod_rewrite instead of mod_authz_host

For example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php

RewriteEngine On

# Exception for error documents
RewriteRule ^40[34]\.php$ - [L]

# Forbid all other requests, except those from IP address
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=203.0.113.111
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```